# Best way to override a installed packge method

Tags: python

I am using `django-compress for compression`. According to need I want to change on of the functions in `..../dist-packages/compress/utils.py`. How can I `override` this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import compress.utils
utils.compress.function_to_override = overriding_function
```

[Monkey patch](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Monkey_patch) it. You'll need to do this before `utils` is imported anywhere else.

Alternatively, you could create a new Python module, like this:

```
# fakeutils.py
from compress.utils import *

# make the following line match exactly the overridden function
def function_to_override(var1, etc1, etc2):
    # your version of the function
```

Then import that module instead:

```
import fakeutils as utils
```

Comment: Isn't it enough to monkey patch once before utils is imported anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, you're right of course, I'm just used to putting it everywhere when there isn't a set entry point (using my second method).

Comment: what about variables? If the function takes some.

Comment: In monkey patch case:function_to_override takes (arg1,agr2,arg3) but how can I pass this argument to overriding function. Because already this method is called some where in the installed package

Comment: `import` the module and monkey patch it __before__ it's `import`ed anywhere else. Then your function will get called instead of the original function. You can't override a function that is being called before you patch it, so your question doesn't really make sense -- the original function will never receive the arguments, your replacement function will.

Comment: ok my situation is like: compress/templatetages/compressed.py have some class "Foo". In this "Foo" class utils method is imported. How can I monkey patch this before it get imported.

Comment: At the top of your `appconfig.py` or whatever duplicate the _exact_ import from `compressed.py` and then patch it. Assuming `appconfig.py` is loaded before `compressed.py` it will work.